# Hold unless open profit is greater than 1% in Pine Script V4 strategy

Tags: pine-script

I would like my strategy to only sell if the open profit is positive. otherwise hold.
What elements would I use to make that happen?

Comment: I figured it out, all I had to do was add,

and (strategy.openprofit > 0)

as one of my "SELL" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I had to do was add, and (strategy.openprofit > 0) as one of my "SELL" conditions.

Maybe this is helpful to someone.

Now my trading bot is 100% profitable, though sometimes trades must be held for up to a few days. It's worth it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).